# I'm unable to pass props to my component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-props

I'm new to React and trying to pass data between components and I have obtained the `dish` and `rate` values from **state** and passed these values as **props** to my `<Checkout />` component. But when I try to render the props in Checkout component, I don't see any props. Am I doing something wrong here?

**Menu.js:**

```
function cart() {
  let newMenu = []
  for (var key in props.counter) {
    if (props.counter[key] > 0) {
      props.dishDetails(key)
      props.details[key].rate *= props.counter[key]
      newMenu.push(props.details[key])
    }
  }
  newMenu.map((item) => {
    console.log(item.dish, item.rate)
  })
  newMenu.map((item) => (
    <Checkout key={item.dish} details={item.dish} money={item.rate} />
  ))
}
```

`newMenu` has all the `dish` and `rate` values that are to be passed to `Checkout`.

**Menu.js:**

```
<div className="buttons flex justify-center items-center mt-6">
  <Link to="/checkout" className="btn2 btn-1" onClick={cart}>
    <svg>
      <rect x="0" y="0" fill="none" width="100%" height="100%" />
    </svg>
    GO TO CART
  </Link>
</div>
```

I have called Checkout component inside the callback function and assigned the props but in the Checkout component I don't see the props.

This is the props seen in Checkout component:

[image]

Comment: Someone is incorrectly teaching people to use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for looping arrays. 'map' creates a new array, if you want to loop through an array, please use `forEach` or `for`.

Comment: Can you create a sandbox? Form the code you posted, it is not clear what you are trying to do. `newMenu` is a local variable in `cart` function and when you _call_ the `cart` function, it affects nothing at UI or in component _state_.

Comment: Is your ```cart``` function getting called?

Comment: Yes the cart function is getting called. My issue isn't with the mapping of elements. The only problem is that the values that I get from newMenu aren't getting passed as props i.e. the details and money